# IE8 a href for local files opens new window despite target="_Self"

Tags: javascript, html

My set of files are all on a local server, not http. If I use:

```
    <a href="somefile.htm" target="_Self">click here</a>
```

it opens the file in a new window. _Top is also ignored, and I get a new window. I can get around it by using window.open() but for various reasons we need to avoid javascript.

I'm interested to know why the a href target is ignored.

Comment: have you tried lowercase? `target='_self'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `_self` (or just leave it off altogether): http://jsfiddle.net/rsmRA/ -- this is a case-sensitive value.

According to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/HTML/Elements/a#HTML_Attributes), it doesn't seem like it's *supposed* to be case-sensitive, so I guess this is a browser bug.  If you set it to anything except those keywords it is a "browsing-context name."  You can see this in action by clicking that same link twice; you will notice that it only opens a new window the first time and reloads that window the second time.

Comment: if I don't include a target, it should open in the same frame by default. But it doesn't. I've just discovered I have the same issue with chrome.

Comment: @user1664208 are you sure you don't have some JavaScript going on or it's wrapped in another `<a>` that's causing a problem?

Comment: you know what, using lower case 's' in 'self' did the trick. Crazy! All these years I thought I had the correct syntax and thought the lowercase versions were incorrect.